# How create static trendline object on chart by MQL4?

Tags: mql4

I want a down trend line whenever the highest candle in the previous 500 bars is higher than latest 5 candles highest bar. However the trend line is created the first time but does not update.

```
int highestCandle=iHighest(Symbol(),0,MODE_HIGH,500,0);
if(High[highestCandle]>High[5])
{
ObjectCreate(0,"HT",OBJ_TREND,0,Time[highestCandle],High[highestCandle],Time[0],High[0]);
ObjectSetInteger(0,"HT",OBJPROP_COLOR,clrBlue); ObjectSetInteger(0,"HT",OBJPROP_STYLE,STYLE_SOLID); ObjectSetInteger(0,"HT",OBJPROP_RAY,true);
}
```

I do not want to delete this object and recreate on every new tick, I would just like it to be updated on the chart.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have already created your object, trying to create it again will not move the coordinates. You need to use [ObjectMove](https://docs.mql4.com/objects/objectmove). Try the following code:

```
int highestCandle=iHighest(Symbol(),0,MODE_HIGH,500,0);
if(High[highestCandle]>High[5])
{
   ObjectCreate(0,"HT",OBJ_TREND,0,Time[highestCandle],High[highestCandle],Time[0],High[0]);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,"HT",OBJPROP_COLOR,clrBlue);
   ObjectSetInteger(0,"HT",OBJPROP_STYLE,STYLE_SOLID); 
   ObjectSetInteger(0,"HT",OBJPROP_RAY,true);
   ObjectMove("HT",0,Time[highestCandle],High[highestCandle]);
   ObjectMove("HT",1,Time[0],High[0]);
}
```

Comment: thanks bro.appreciate your help .I need thing is to trade breakout trendline .So need to be static trendline in draw place and when price breakout this line.its work done. After that when condition meet again. this trend will draw again. if object move trendline.price breakout cannot be set because trend place move from one bar to bar , How can fix it bro.

Comment: I think this has answered your original question. If so, please mark the answer as accepted and post a new question if you have other problems.

Comment: I already highlight static trendline on original question

Comment: Hi @leon, your original question asked why your code does not update the trend line position as the bars change, my answer addresses this question. As per [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com) guidelines and the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), you should mark this answer as accepted and open a new question for any follow up issues you have.